# how to make chrome extension with options that allow you to open settings of chrome in new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

today i'm facing problem that i can't solve my problem is very simple i wanted to make
chrome extension that allow me to do some easy steps exomple i wanted to open chrome setting
in new tab with my extension i did setting botton in the extension and the clear browser data
and open extension of chrome but when i try to open it when i click nothing happen it keep
give me this error =

Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://settings/

and my code is this =

```
<div class="flex"><a href="chrome://settings/" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-cogs" style="color:darksalmon "></i></a></div>
```

please help me to solve this error please and thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the standard HTML anchor to open an internal Chrome link. Chrome’s links are not valid navigation protocols, only these are:

```
<a href="https://somesite.com">Website</a>

<a href="mailto:someone@abc.com">Email</a>

<a href="tel:+652356256">Telephone</a>

<a href="#para2">Document Section</a>

<a href="javascript:alert('Hello');">JavaScript</a>
```

For a internal Chrome link you should open a new tab and pass the internal link to it via the Tab API...

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

Use the function "create"...

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url':'chrome://settings/','selected':true}, function(tab){

  /// Whatever else goes in here...

});
```

Comment: hi thank you i don't know how to use the fonction create and where i need to put it please help me thank you between i don't know very much in javascript programing thank you men and between where to put it exactly in popup.html or manifest.json sorry men xD